Cannot find module './doc/workbook' in Exceljs
I am using ExcelJs to export some grid data. It worked fine on my local, but while deploying it using Jenkins I am getting Error: Cannot find module './doc/workbook'.
Any idea why is this is happening and how to fix it.
